# Change ActionBar Title

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

My main Activity consists of a `fragment`.I am setting up the action bar title on onResume() method of Activity as

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
    }
```

which shows the action bar title as `"My Account"`.And when i call a fragment i set the title on onResume() method of fragment as

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Connected Accounts");
    }
```

which displays the title as `'Connected Accounts'`.However when i go back to the activity it still displays the title as `'Connected Accounts'`,whereas it should display as `'My Account'`.
Please help i know there is something missing in this peculiar case.Thanks

Comment: No it's not. You are making the wrong assumption  that the activity is pause while you are displaying the fragment

Comment: so where should i call it??

Comment: You could call in in on `onPause` inside your fragment to "My Account" again. That should do the trick

Comment: it is difficult to answer without knowing what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just override onDetach() in your Fragment Class.
add this code in your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
    getActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
}
```

Comment: thanks! Would  prefer this answer rather than calling inside onPause() inside fragment.